# Angular issues with iOS webView

Tags: javascript, ios, html, angularjs

I created an HTML/Angular app, I created a frame in iOS that will load my html and show it in the web-view.
When i run the app i get the following error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/itzikkedar/Sites/ADMI/partials/main.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. 
I used the error i got in chrome cause its the same issue.
I understand that this is a browser/web-view security issue. But all html files in angular called in ajax, That mean i cant use angular with web-view?
Please assist  with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your link refers to a file on your Mac with protocol file.
You should try to use relative links in your route.